# Determine if data has been received in Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm writing a program that sends an object from my `LandingPage` component, to my `Details` component. When the object is empty, it means my Details component was loaded before my landingpage, I want to be able to determine when the object is empty in my code.

I receive the `LandingPage` data object from a service in my:

**resultpage.component.ts** *( /details route )*

```
details: Object;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.details = this.TitleService.getTitle(); //store our LandingPage info into details
}
```

When someone loads the `/details` route directly, the received object will be empty. But I cannot figure out how to determine whether the object is empty or not.

How can I determine whether someone is directly loading my `/details` route? Should I be checking whether the received object is empty, or is there a better way?

Comment: do you want stop loading /details if user directly loaded ?

Comment: No I still want it to render /details completely. The objective is when it's directly loaded, I call my service to get the information that is missing

Comment: You are doing it right.
You need to check it in ngInit() function weather the details object is empty or not.

Another way to achieve this functionality is that instead of loading it before navigating to the details page, you always pass id of the object to details page(component) and load it in details component in ngInit() function

Comment: thanks! I found a way to check for an empty object, so everything works now. But I think I might try your suggestion in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can check to see if an object is empty by doing the following:

```
if (obj && (Object.keys(obj).length === 0));
```

which will return true if the object is empty.